# Servers Hangs when finds session code. I'm using Sequelize to store the session

Tags: node.js, express, session, sequelize.js

I have an app that is already working. The problem began when I coded the session part of it. The server hangs when finds this lines of code in the controller:

```js
req.session.save(() => {
            req.session.loggedIn = true;
         });
```

The user-routes.js controller is:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
console.log(__filename);


router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/verify', (req, res) => {

    try {
        // HERE *********************************************************************
         req.session.save(() => {
            req.session.loggedIn = true;
         });

        const messages = {};
        res.render('dashboard', {messages, loggedIn:req.session.loggedIn},);
    } catch (e) {
    }
});

router.get('/newUser', (req, res) => {
    res.render('newUser');
});

router.post('/saveUser', (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard');
});
module.exports = router;
```

and my server.js is:

```js
const root = require('app-root-path')
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const session = require('express-session');
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const routes = require('./controllers/index');

const configSession = {
    secret: 'this is a secret',
    cookie: {maxAge: 86400,},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new SequelizeStore({db: sequelize}),
};

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(root + path.sep + 'public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(routes);
app.use(session(configSession));

const hbs = exphbs.create();
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

const run = async () => {
    //const sequelizeResult = await sequelize.sync({force: true});
    //console.log("---> sequelizeResult :" + (sequelizeResult));
    await app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log('Server listening on port %j', PORT);
    });
}


//RUN 
run();
```

I am using MySQL. I stopped the server, dropped the db tables, create and seed them again.

What could be the problem? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try printing the error in the catch and sending a response

Comment: Followed your advice @Ariel. It prints "Cannot read property 'save' of undefined". Si, the session is not working?

Comment: Looks like the problem is this: SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'tech_blog_db.session' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize needs to sync the tables (and add the session table) when the server starts. I am uncommenting the line where sequelize.sync() is called

```js
const run = async () => {
    const sequelizeResult = await sequelize.sync({force: true});
    //console.log("---> sequelizeResult :" + (sequelizeResult));
    await app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log('Server listening on port %j', PORT);
    });
}
```

That solved the problem.